# Convert string to image (any format bitmap or ico most prefered) wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have few numbers which i wanted to show in tray icon... for that i need to convert those numbers into icon or any bitmap image ....need help is their any class or property in wpf c# to do so.. any method .. the method i tried is not working...

```
Font fnt = new Font("Tahoma", 8 );
fntheight += fnt.Height;
int maxheight = 0;

if (state == true)
    maxheight = height + fntheight + fntheight;
else
    maxheight = height + fntheight;

Graphics grf = Graphics.FromImage(myimg);
Image newimg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, maxheight);
Graphics newgrf = Graphics.FromImage(newimg);

newgrf.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, width, height);
```

but this code in not working in current wpf c# .net 4+

Comment: **How** is it not working? Does it explode?

Comment: Your code is full of undefined symbols. Or is that not what you mean by “not working”?

Comment: its just a snap from an old project... i just posted it to get started with...it work well with old c# framework <4 but now with my current 4.5 framework...

Comment: I assume the original code was for WinForms.  Please post what you tried so far for WPF.

Comment: Please check this post http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/generate-image-from-text-using-c-or-convert-text-in-to-image-using-c/

Comment: thanks for reply.. yes above is WinForm Code i have no idea how to do this in WPF C# Font now present their.. No image can be passed in bitmap constructor and so on... i am clue less right now... above post is also not working tried at ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MikMagic You can convert from System.Drawing.Bitmap to System.Windows.Media.Image via BitmapSource object.

See [this Code Project's article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104929/Bitmap-to-BitmapSource) and [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the link @yukitos.. it helped a lot..

Answer (score 5):

First you need to add:

```
Using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Interop;
```

To convert text to Bitmap:

```
public Bitmap TextToBitmap(string txt, string fontname, int fontsize, Color bgcolor, Color fcolor, int Width, int Height)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            Font font = new Font(fontname, fontsize);
            graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bgcolor), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            graphics.DrawString(txt, font, new SolidBrush(fcolor), 0, 0);
            graphics.Flush();
            font.Dispose();
            graphics.Dispose();
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

To convert Bitmap to BitmapImage:

```
public BitmapImage BitmapToBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

        BitmapSource bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap,
            IntPtr.Zero, 
            Int32Rect.Empty, 
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BitmapImage bitImage = new BitmapImage();

        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
        encoder.Save(memoryStream);

        bitImage.BeginInit();
        bitImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
        bitImage.EndInit();

        memoryStream.Close();

        return bitImage;
    }
```

To set the converted BitmapImage to an element that uses `System.Windows.Media.Brush`

```
    public void SetBitmapImage()
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = TextToBitmap(*whatever goes here);

        *Element.Background = new ImageBrush(BitmapToBitmapImage(bmp));
    }
```

To set the converted BitmapImage to an element that uses `System.Windows.Media.Image`

```
    public void SetBitmapImage()
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = TextToBitmap(*whatever goes here);

        *Element.Source = BitmapToBitmapImage(bmp);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code... their are few issues Bitmap doesnot exist in wpf c# it has bitmapimage but that does not support giving width and height.. it has 3 overload each take URI which we don't have.. Similar for Font and Solid Brush happens...

Comment: Thanks for answer your code is fine.. but the problem is, this can't work with wpf, because if i wish to view this image i can't use any of existing wpf control because the image classed their take System.Windows.Media Image with unfortunately c't be converted to SYstem.Drawing.Bitmap.. any other suggestions...